# Number of grid points in a polygon

Tags: geometry, area, polygons

Following problem:
I want to approximate the number of grid points in a polygon, based on the condition that the distance of the grid points are variable.
What i need is an approximation, i am aware that a precise information is hard to obtain.

I first started experimenting with several numbers to calculate the number of grid points in a square and developed a formula:
$$
(\frac{\sqrt{x} }{y} +1 )^{2} 
$$
x is the surface area and y is the distance of each grid point from each other.

(quick question: is there an already existing formula for or a theorem?)

Anyway i want to approximate the number of grid points with a distance of 7 Kilometers based on the area of Germany, which is about 357.000 square kilometers.
Therefore i thought of drawing the map of germany in a coordinate system with integer coordinates and use Pick's theorem, but my map must be huge if a want a distance of 7km for each point and the job would be very labourious.

Is there a smarter solution? Like mentioned before, i need a realistic estimate not a exact number. Thank you very much.

Comment: It depends on how you want to solve it, but maybe you're also open to a computational approach. You should be able to find a very good estimate by roughly defining a polygon representing the borders of Germany and then iteratively applying http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon for each of your grid points. It won't be fast, but it'll be a very realistic esitmate.

Comment: I don't get that exactly, how can a test that identifies a given point in it's location will be helpful to get the amount of gridpoints with a certain distance from each other in a polygon? And yes: I am open for every kind of approach.

Comment: Think of each grid point being the lower-left corner of a square $7$ km on a side. The squares sort of cover Germany --- they may cover a bit of Denmark and Poland and the Czech Republic, as well, but they will also miss bits of Germany near the eastern and southern borders, so they'll pretty nearly add up to the area of Germany. So, the number of points is roughly the area of Germany divided by the area of a square, $357000/49$.

Comment: I think I should emphasize that my proposal is a rather brute force approach mostly suited for a computer program. A picture is probably worth a thousand words, so check this program I put together for the basic idea: http://plnkr.co/edit/cbAAaB9vOJjaRhSFWVRT?p=preview

Comment: Brilliant! Thats brute force approach solves my problem. Thank you very much! @GerryMyerson: Thank you too, how accurate is the approximation?

Comment: That depends on the shape of Germany.

Comment: To give you some idea of the difficulties involved, even if Germany were a perfect circle, there would still be unsolved problems concerning the accuracy of the approximation. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem